# How is it possible that all Riemannian manifold admit a covering by convex balls?

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a sphere. A panoramic view on Riemannian manifolds stated that "Every point of a Riemannian manifold lives at the center of a convex ball such that any two points in that ball are joined by a unique segment contained in that ball."

Now, the definition for total convexity is that all geodesics whose end points are contained in a subset $A \subset M$ are themselves necessarily contained in $A$. This tells me that all proper subsets of a sphere are not totally convex. Then how is it possible that there exists a covering by convex balls?

Comment: The statement doesn't mention total convexity, only convexity. Am I missing something?

Comment: Same as your other question: total convexity if not a well set notion and depends on the choice of the author. The definition here of convexity is not that all geodesic segments joining two points of the ball is contained on the ball: it says that there is a unique such geodesic inside the ball. If you want the previous to be true, you should add "unique minimizing geodesic segment"

Comment: As for your question, the notion that explains it well is the *convexity radius* (see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0341) for instance)